# A problem involving Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

This is the problem: Given the ODE $x'=f(x)$, suppose that $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R^2$, and $f$ satisfies the hipoteses of Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem, if exists $V:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is constant over the solutions, i.e., $V$ is a first integral, then $f$ has no cicle limit.

I think that I didn't understand the question, becouse by hipoteses, the $w$-limit is compact, not empty, and don't have critical points, so by the theorem the only possible $\omega$-limits are periodic orbits, so how I should prove that is not a periodic orbit to?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by $V$ is constant over the solutions? Is $V$ the potential function?

Comment: See these notes: http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/mb8/lect4.pdf

Closed orbits are impossible in a gradient system.

Comment: $V$ is not necessary the potential function, $V$ is a first integral for the system.